# role and difference between default_supplier and supplier

Tags: odoo

hi everyone while begging supplier is a boolean field of res.partner class that determines whether the partner is supplier or not... well I have two questions:

1- what is the difference between context={'default_supplier':True and context={'supplier':True

2 in the form fleet_vehicle_contract_form there is a field provider with context={'default_supplier':True, but that shows all partner not the only vendor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends.  Context is designed to carry specific, relevant information back and forth between the client and server, as well as through different functions run from a single action.  Context keys that start with 'default_' automatically trigger a response in the default_get() function of the ORM.  Using context={'default_some_field_name':'some_value'} means that when you're loading a form to create a new record, the field called 'some_field_name' will be automatically assigned the default value of 'some_value'.  In your example, that would be used from the Suppliers menu within Purchasing so that whenever you create a new partner, it's automatically a supplier as well as a partner.

The other option, context={'supplier':True} doesn't necessarily mean anything specific.  That's just some syntax that is relevant to a Python function.  It could be anything you wanted - context={'important_extra_thing_to_do':'ABC'} would be fine as well to program into a view or action, if your Python code checked the context for the key 'important_extra_thing_to_do'.

2. Context values aren't filters of information, that's the job of the Domain.  What probably should be in place in that instance is:

This means that the only partners that are visible must already be suppliers, and if you're creating a new partner directly from this field, it will automatically fill in the value of the supplier field as True.

Comment: please you have exemple in odoo with context={'some_field_name':'some_value'} (not default). thx